# Is there any type for datetimes or timestamps in PineScript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I want to create and export a custom type in my library. For this I need to store a single datetime/timestamp value. Is there any primitive type for the declaration?

e.g.:

```
export type VerticalLineData
  float price_level
  ????? candle_timestamp_from
  ????? candle_timestamp_to
```

It would not matter if this was a primitive built-in, but I would prefer storing the results of `time` or `timenow` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Pine are using UNIX timestamps for time, so type for time is just int.
You can see reutrn type of time, timenow or timestamp() in Pine ref.